# Find a basis for subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let 
$$
W = \left[ 
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
x_4
\end{pmatrix}
\in R^4\mid x_1+x_3=x_4
 \right]
$$

This is what I've done so far. I can re-arrange the equation to
$
x_1=-3x_3+x_4
$
and from this get the basis

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-3 \\
0 \\
1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix} \;
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I'm not too sure if I have done this correct. Can anyone confirm? Should $x_{2}=0$ since it does not appear in the equation?

Answer (score 1):

***Hint(s):***

$x_2$ can be any real number. The condition $x_1 + x_3 = x_4$ is independent of it. Now notice that for a vector $\underline x = (x_1 \; x_2 \; x_3 \; x_4 )^T$ to be in $W$ it must satisfy the equation $x_1 + x_3 = x_4$. Notice then that $\underline x \in W$ if and only if $\underline x$ is of the form, $$\underline x =  (x_1, \; x_2, \; x_3, \; x_3 + x_1 )^T = x_1(1,0,0,1)^T + x_2( 0,1,0,0)^T +  x_3 ( 0,0,1,1 )^T $$

where $x_1, x_2, x_3$ can be any real number or they can be viewed as arbitrary *scalars*.